# How to make SQL Server table primary key auto increment with some characters

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I have a table like this :

```
create table ReceptionR1 
(
   numOrdre             char(20)             not null,
   dateDepot            datetime             null,
   ...
)
```

I want to increment my `id` field (`numOrdre`) like `'225/2015','226/2015',...,'1/2016'` etc. What should I have to do for that?

2015 means the actual year.

Please let me know any possible way.

Comment: really apply both tags "mysql" and "sql-server"?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Since you used MySQL as a tag in your question, If you were using MySQL, you can use MyISAM engine to make 2 column as a primary PRIMARY KEY (id1,id2) and then you could create a view to concat both to column to make them look like what your asking.  another thing you could probably do "instead of the view"  is create trigger on insert to generate the string that your are looking for. Good reading http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: This can be done but not automatically. The effort required is senseless

Comment: Thanks for response , but it doesn't have relation with my question, for me , I have to increment two things : the first number (225 for ex) and the year after "/" , when 2016 started , the first number should become 1 . I hope my question was clear because I don't have a good english :)

Comment: Even if it was effortless it is a horrible idea

Comment: Someone informed me that I have to use a Trigger . I don't know how to use it or If it's true what he was saying

Comment: Separate data design from how you want data reported.    What are you trying to achieve?   Right now this is not a good data design.

Answer (score 1):

You really, and I mean Really don't want to do such a thing, especially as your primary key. You better use a simple `int identity` column for you primary key and add a non nullable create date column of type `datetime2` with a default value of `sysDateTime()`.

Create the increment number by year either as a calculated column or by using an instead of insert trigger (if you don't want it to be re-calculated each time). This can be done fairly easy with the use of `row_number` function.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said - don't use this as your **primary key**! But you *could* do the following, if you're on SQL Server 2012 or newer:

```
-- step 1 - create a sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.SeqOrderNo AS INT
START WITH 1001  -- start with whatever value you need
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CYCLE
NO CACHE;

-- create your table - use INT IDENTITY as your primary key
CREATE TABLE dbo.ReceptionR1 
(
   ID INT IDENTITY 
      CONSTRAINT PK_ReceptionR1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   dateDepot DATE NOT NULL,
   ...
   -- add a colum called "SeqNumber" that gets filled from the sequence
   SeqNumber INT,

   -- you can add a *computed* column here
   OrderNo = CAST(YEAR(dateDepot) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(SeqNumber AS VARCHAR(4))
)
```

So now, when you insert a row, it has a **proper** and well defined primary key (`ID`), and when you fill the `SeqNumber` with

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ReceptionR1 (dateDepot, SeqNumber)
VALUES (SYSDATETIME(), NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SeqOrderNo)
```

then the `SeqNumber` column gets the next value for the sequence, and the `OrderNo` computed column gets filled with `2015/1001`, `2015/1002` and so forth.

Now when 2016 comes around, you just reset the sequence back to a starting value:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.SeqOrderNo RESTART WITH 1000;
```

and you're done - the rest of your solution works as before.

If you want to make sure you never accidentally insert a duplicate value, you can even put a unique index on your `OrderNo` column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Once more, you cannot use the combo field as your primary key.  This solution sort or works on earlier versions of SQL and calculates the new annual YearlySeq counter automatically - but you had better have an index on dateDepot and you might still have issues if there are many, many (100's of thousands) of rows per year.

In short: fight the requirement.

Given

```
create table dbo.ReceptionR1 
(
ReceptionR1ID       INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
YearlySeq           INT  ,
dateDepot           datetime  DEFAULT (GETDATE())  ,
somethingElse       varchar(99) null,
numOrdre            as LTRIM(STR(YearlySeq)) + '/' + CONVERT(CHAR(4),dateDepot,111)
) 


GO
CREATE TRIGGER R1Insert on dbo.ReceptionR1 for   INSERT
as
UPDATE tt SET YearlySeq = ISNULL(ii.ReceptionR1ID - (SELECT MIN(ReceptionR1ID) FROM  dbo.ReceptionR1 xr WHERE DATEPART(year,xr.dateDepot) = DATEPART(year,ii.dateDepot) and xr.ReceptionR1ID <> ii.ReceptionR1ID ),0) + 1
    FROM dbo.ReceptionR1 tt
        JOIN inserted ii on ii.ReceptionR1ID = tt.ReceptionR1ID 
GO

insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('dumb')
insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('requirements')
insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('lead')
insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('to')
insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('big')
insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('problems')
insert into ReceptionR1 (somethingElse) values ('later')

select * from ReceptionR1
```